# XFCE4 terminal to never show tabs

Tags: xfce4-terminal

The terminal program `xfce4-terminal` has an option `MiscAlwaysShowTabs` to even show a tab if there is only one shell window open. The reason is to prevent window resizing when the number of open shell windows changes between one and two or back.

Yet the tab bar contains hardly a wealth of information and I would not mind getting rid of it completely, i.e. to never show it, even if I then have to guess how many tabs are open.

Any chance?

Comment: What is your xfce version and xfce4-terminal version?

Comment: In my case (xfce4-terminal 0.8.7.4 (Xfce 4.12)), I need to close all instances of xfce4-terminal for it to work.